# Calculate 2 variables that reference and are dependent on each other? Similar to how excel calculates cells?

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm trying to convert an excel spreadsheet calculator into a javascript calculator. I'm 90% of the way there but I'm getting caught up on one part where two variables are being defined.

Two of the cells on the excel spreadsheet reference each other, excel somehow calculates both of these on the fly at the same time. Javascript, to the best of my knowledge is compiled in order, top to bototm.

Therefore, for the example below, I can't calculate variable B which is dependent on variable C because C hasn't been defined yet. Both of these also reply on a value which is calculated previously based on the users input in the calculator, so I can't pre calculate anything (Can I?).

So is there a way to force javascript to somehow calculate both at the same time?

Example:

```
var A = ?, 
    B = C-A, 
    C = B-2;
```

I'm not a developer, so sorry for any loopholes/mistakes in my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The “new” values for B and C should be stored in different variables than the old ones, until you have finished the calculations anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add event listener for change in input. It can be used to calculate values of B and C everytime you make any changes in the input.

something like...

```
var B, C;
var input = document.getElementById("input_id");
input.addEventListener("change", function (){
    var A = document.getElementById("input_id").value
    B = C-A, 
    C = B-2;
})
```

So everytime when you make any changes in A, B and C will have new values depending on new value of A.

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure about how well JavaScript will deal with this style of calculations but you can structure it somehwhat like,

var a = 2;

var b = 1;

var c;

c = a - b; // expected 1.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that A is a dynamic value which differs depending on the users input, so I can't expect or assume an output. I've updated the question to reflect this. Sorry, but thanks for the reply!